# How can i allow iphone app to login using facebook using devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3, api, devise

I want users to login with their facebook account through devise from iphone app.

consider when i send the id and password as

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept: application/json'   -X POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in  -d "{'user' : { 'email' : 'sample@gmail.com', 'password' : 'asdfghjkl'}}"
```

then it produces

```
{"user":{"authentication_token":"34734t374hfjeg266272","email":"sample@gmail.com"}}
```

I use the authentication token for the next request as

```
curl -L 'localhost:3000/posts.json?auth_token=34734t374hfjeg266272'
```

and i get the values from the table as json and similarly how can i do it with facebook account in devise?

I have omniauth used in my web app and i could login as facebook user from my web app but how could i do it for iphone app?

Answer (score 1):

You may use iOS6's social framework.

```
WWDC 2012 Session Videos“Integration With Facebook, Twitter and Sina Weibo”
```

(https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=306)

Or, you may use Facebook SDK.

http://developers.facebook.com/ios/

Or, you may use oauth library like gtm-oauth

gtm-oauth (Google Toolbox for Mac - OAuth Controllers)

http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/wiki/